# Web app version in Tomcat Manager

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, version

How can I configure my web application for deployment in Tomcat so that Tomcat Manager shows the version in the table that lists all applications installed (/manager/html/list)?

Currently it shows *"None Specified"* for all apps, including itself. I am using Tomcat 7.0.11.

Comment: How do you want to specify the version? Which tomcat are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 7.0.11.

Comment: So you imply the ##X version? Isn't that shown as different context/app?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by ##X ?

Comment: sorry, my bad, it's not about that version

Comment: Actually I think you were on the right track. I tried the naming the war myapp#002.war and copying it into the webapps directory but Tomcat rejected the war complaining it had an invalid name. I'm looking at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The version is the one specified when deploying the application through the manager.

See [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely):

> tag: Specifying a tag name, this allows associating the deployed webapp with a version number. The application version can be later redeployed when needed using only the tag.

Also, you can deploy multiple versions of the same war by adding the version after ## (e.g. myApp##1.0.war, myApp##1.1.war).  The manager will show this version in the overview.

Comment: I tried this but the version in Tomcat Manager is still "None Specified".

Comment: which? the ##? IF so, then only the first part of my answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Putting <version>1.0</version> in the web.xml did not work.  Naming the war file myapp##002.war did.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that the version number requires two hashes, like this: `myApp##1.1.war`. Using a single hash will change the deployment path to `myApp/1.1/` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: New documentation (Tomcat 7.0.96) does not mention this. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely

Answer (score 14):

With maven set the output war file name:

```
...
<artifactId>MyTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
...
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}##${project.version}</finalName>
</build>
...
```

Output -> **MyTest##0.0.1.war**

Or simple rename war-file with format **file_name##version.war** ;)

Answer (score 2):

For maven, use the tomcat plugin configuration path :

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/${project.artifactId}##${project.version}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

finalName trick didn't worked for me.

Comment: This is it for the automatic deploy process. You are the real MVP.

Answer (score 1):

- In my case, myapp#v0.2.1 notation does not work.
- I tried the tag parameter, not work too.. (call with maven)

Referred to [Apache Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#naming), I tried to deploy war file manually and it works.

I do not understand why it does not work with maven tomcat deploy

```
Configuration : Simple Java EE/restlet app with Tomcat 7 / Java 7 / Maven 4
```

Comment: that's because you need to use double hash.  myapp##v0.2.1 should work.

Comment: Wait what? Maven 4? I wanna try it too!

Comment: I tried double Hash, and it works.
With Maven tricks, I succeeded in building and deploying it with tomcat manager perfectly

Comment: I used Tomcat 8.0.28, tried with the <tag> in pom.xml, as well as with the ##, but it didn't work. I can see that maven prints in the console http://localhost:8028/manager/text/deploy?path=...&update=true&tag=1.1. But it does not show up in the Version column. At last we decided adding the version number in the  <display-name>Application v1.1</display-name>  tag itself so that it gets displayed in the display Name column itself

Comment: At `web.xml`: `<web-app blahblah><display-name>sometext</display-name>…`

Answer (score 1):

I am running `Tomcat 8.0.30` and to add a version in *Tomcat Web Application Manager* one can simply rename MyApp (under webapps folder) to `MyApp##1.0.2` without creating `.war` file.

If you want to create `.war` file, follow these steps:

- Navigate to Tomcat webapps folder, on the address bar type cmd or cmd.exe or else you can open cmd and navigate to your tomcat webapps directory

[image]

- Enter this cmd - `jar cvf MyApp.war .`

Here MyApp is *name of Application*, `.war` is the extension for creating war file (also called as *Web Application Archive*) and . represents current directory where war file will be created..

After doing this, you'll see `MyApp.war` file under webapps. Now just rename to `MyApp##1.0.2.war` and the server will automatically reload the context with name.

[image]

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the "tomcat7-maven-plugin" plugin dependency, you can easily set the variable "warName" of the "maven-war-plugin" to the value   `<warName>${project.artifactId}##${project.version}</warName>`.