# Tomcat war with version number deployed by Maven plugin

Tags: tomcat7, war, maven-tomcat-plugin

i use maven3 to deploy to tomcat7, and in the process, it builds the war with a version number, and when the maven plugin deploys it, the version number is no longer part of the war, and the path i set works properly (all of this works as expected, no problems).
the plugin i'm using for the deploy is groupId "org.codehaus.mojo"

My question is how this happens, because i need to replicate this process when i manually deploy a war with a version number.
I want the version number taken out, and i want to set a path, other that the war name.

Looking for help to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  element in the pom.
And move to new version of this plugin which is now located at Apache http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and checked it into https://github.com/vipup/java-maven-war-example . Thanks a lot of advice from [SO_Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347326/web-app-version-in-tomcat-manager) ..

In short : the deployment_URL should contain the  version  of deploy-WAR. Then Tomcat process it always correctly. I added in the project even possibilities to set version as command - line - parameters.

So, just try:

```
# mvn tomcat:redeploy -DtheBN4tomcat=HALILUJA
```